# Replace character after key press in CRichEditCtrl MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, cricheditctrl, crichedit

I want to redirect Space key press action to display another char (whitespace char '·').

What handler or windows message can I use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to intercept the key in `PreTranslateMessage`

```
BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* msg)
{
    if (msg->hwnd == m_RichEdit.m_hWnd)
    {
        if (msg->message == WM_CHAR)
        {
            if (msg->wParam == ' ')
            {
                msg->wParam = '.';
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

   return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(msg);
}
```

Edit:
To insert unicode characters with Alt key:

Declare member data:

```
int m_key_value;
```

Initialize `m_key_value = 0;`

To check if Alt key is pressed down:

```
BOOL IsKeyDown(int vkCode)
{
    return GetAsyncKeyState(vkCode) & 0x8000;
}
```

We want to see if number keys are pressed while Alt key is down. We check `WM_SYSKEYUP` (don't check `WM_SYSKEYDOW` because it results in repeat characters)

```
BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* msg)
{
    if (msg->hwnd == m_RichEdit.m_hWnd)
    {
        if (msg->message == WM_SYSKEYUP && IsKeyDown(VK_MENU))
        {
            int i = msg->wParam;
            if (i >= '0' && i <= '9')
                i -= '0';
            else if (i >= VK_NUMPAD0 && i <= VK_NUMPAD9)
                i -= VK_NUMPAD0;
            if (i >= 0 && i <= 9)
            {
                m_key_value *= 10;
                m_key_value += i;
                TRACE("m_key_value = %d\n", m_key_value);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        if (msg->message == WM_KEYUP && msg->wParam == VK_MENU && m_key_value)
        {
            TRACE("WM_KEYUP RESULT %d\n", m_key_value);
            if (m_key_value == 160) m_key_value = '.';
            m_RichEdit.PostMessage(WM_CHAR, m_key_value, 0);
            m_key_value = 0;
            return TRUE;
        }

    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I only had to remove return TRUE;.

Comment: This doesn't work for some special characters inserted using Alt + Unicode method. For example NoBreakSpace (code: 0xA0, command Alt + 0 + 1 + 6 + 0) is not changed with another character. Is there another way to do this or to adapt this solution? I have tried to send another windows message with the wanted char and skip CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(msg) with no effect.

Comment: Try the above code, push Alt+9+7 and the release Alt

Comment: Solved it with the last code from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523215/change-char-inserted-using-altunicode-in-crichedit/32525675?noredirect=1#comment52937973_32525675

Comment: I had an error earlier, fixed it. This takes input from number pad on the right of keyboard, and numbers on top of keyboard.