# Change char inserted using Alt+Unicode in CRichEdit

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-messages, cricheditctrl, crichedit

I want to change a unicode char inserted using Alt+Unicode code from the keyboard.
I used PretranslateMessage for changing the chars inserted directly from the keyboard and it worked. But with the Alt+Unicode code method it does not.
Here is the code:
Microsoft Word has this functionality when enabling show/hide paragraph marks.

```
BOOL CEmphasizeEdit::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* msg)
{
    if (msg->hwnd == m_hWnd)
    {
        if (msg->message == WM_CHAR)
        {
            if (TheApp.Options.m_bShowWSpaceChars)
            {
                if (msg->wParam == ' ')  // This works in both cases Space key pressed or Alt + 3 + 2 in inserted
                {
                    msg->wParam = '·';
                }
                else if (msg->wParam == (unsigned char)' ') // this does not work
                {
                    msg->wParam = (unsigned char)'°'; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(msg);
}
```

If I insert from the keyboard Alt + 0 + 1 + 6 + 0 which is ' '(No-Break Space), I want the CRichEditCtrl to display '°' or another char that I specify.

How can I handle this to make it work?

Comment: That's not how Word implements the feature. It doesn't **modify** document contents. It merely changes, how contents are displayed.

Comment: Yes, I only want to modify the way it is displayed. This is why I want to redirect the inserted char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get the cursor position send an append string to the control and then set the selection after the inserted character. When this happens I have to skip  CRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(msg);

```
BOOL CEmphasizeEdit::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* msg)
{
    if (msg->hwnd == m_hWnd)
    {
        if (msg->message == WM_CHAR)
        {
            TCHAR text[2];
            text[1] = 0x00;
            BOOL found = 1;

            switch (msg->wParam)
            {
                case 0x20: text[0] = _C('·'); break;
                case 0xA0: text[0] = 0xB0; break;
            }

            CHARRANGE cr;
            GetSel(cr);
            cr.cpMax++;
            cr.cpMin++;

            ReplaceSel(text);
            SetSel(cr);

            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CRichEditCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is reserved for program's close menu.

You should use another sequence like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

`' '` and `(unsigned char)' '` are the same thing, therefore the code never reaches `else if (msg->wParam == (unsigned char)' ')`. You should remove that.

Use `GetAsyncKeyState` to see if `Alt` or `Ctrl` key is pressed down.

```
BOOL IsKeyDown(int vkCode)
{
    return GetAsyncKeyState(vkCode) & 0x8000;
}

...
if (msg->wParam == ' ')
{
    if (IsKeyDown(VK_CONTROL))
        msg->wParam = L'°'; 
    else
        msg->wParam = L'+';
}
...
```

Comment: PretranslateMessage + WM_CHAR retrieves the unicode char inserted using Alt + Unicode code method (Ex: Alt + 9 + 7 which is 'a') but changing it has no effect.

Comment: That makes sense now what you are trying to do. You want to enter unicode char with keyboard shortcuts. Edit your question and explain this in the question. Remove the reference to "changing unicode char" since that's not the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I want to check the unicode char inserted using keyboard shortcuts and if it has a specific value then I want to change it with another value.

Comment: Use `IsKeyDown(VK_MENU)` to check if Alt key is down. Monitor which keys are pressed, use math to add the numbers 9*10+7 = 97